# Matplotlib ploting while ploting

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Please see matplotlib plotting code, but sometimes i am getting the below error.

```
  if np.any(harmonics == 1) or np.any(harmonics == -1):
        for j in range (0,len(harmonics)):
            if harmonics[j] == 1 or harmonics[j]==-1:
                pats+=1
                sense = 'Bearish ' if harmonics[j]==-1 else 'Bullish '
                label = sense + labels[j] + ' found' 
                print(label)
                plt.title(label)
                plt.plot(np.arange(start,i+15),price.values[start:i+15])
                plt.scatter(current_idx,current_pat,c='r')
                filename = str(uuid.uuid1())[:8]
                print(filename)
                plt.savefig(filename)
                plt.close(filename)
                plt.show()
```

trace about the error, when i used the same code huge data input the it is working but same failing if i use less data

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peaks_vis-san.py", line 99, in <module>
    plt.plot(np.arange(start,i+15),price.values[start:i+15])
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2763, in plot
    is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1646, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 216, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 342, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (41,) and (34,)
```

Comment: please make sure any code you post runs correctly.  At the moment, you never define the iteration variable `i`, so the code will fail.  However, I can tell you that the error you are seeing means that you are trying to plot two different arrays of different sizes.  `plt.plot` requires arrays of equal size

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

so i think when u use less dataset the 'values' list in ur code is not of the sufficient length ie.in

```
plt.plot(np.arange(start,i+15),price.values[start:i+15])
```

price.values list doesn't have the indexes till i + 15 and python doesn't raise an error
here and just assumes that u want the values the the list can give,
like Example

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
print(list[0:10])
```

u will get an output like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and therefore u have different length of x,y values to plot, and matplotlib.plot doesnt accept this, and to solve the problem u can do this for the x values

```
np.arange(start,min(len(price.values), i + 15))
```

but beware if at any pt in ur code the length of the values is expected to be i + 15 - start it might break 
hope it helps